# Как через консоль переподключить USB HDD на Raspberry?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, raspberry-pi, device

Периодически по непонятным причинам отвалиается USB диск на удалённом сервере. Сервер на малине с Ubuntu, доступ только по ssh. В списке `fdisk -l` его не видно, `reboot` не помогает. Только если попросить человека там физически переподключить, тогда диск оживает.

Как "разбудить" USB-диск через cli и почему он теряет питание?

Comment: `почему он теряет питание?` — см. кольцевой буфер сообщений программы linux после потери: `$ sudo dmesg`

Comment: На крайний случай  можно и оптрон/твердотельное реле задействовать для подключения-отключения питания к hdd.  Это же RPi! А вообще стоит измерить напряжение питания непосредственно на плате под нагрузкой. Может быть провод или блок питания  заменить..

Comment: @AlexAlex блок питания оригинальный распберри. Модифицировать систему физически нет возможности - она в другой стране. )) Поэтому и интересуюсь как программно разбудить usb. Неужели в линуксе нельзя с консоли питанием usb управлять?

Comment: Можно еще попробовать попросить  подключить диск через активный usb-хаб.. это если дело в питании.